# Canonical way to reference portion of data in vector

Tags: c++, vector, buffer

I'm currently working on a C++ program that has two classes (two that are relevant here). I'm looking for the canonical way (if there is one) to solve the following problem.

There's a Bigger class, which contains a fairly large data buffer (currently a `std::vector`), and a Smaller class that I would also like to access this data. The data buffer in each Smaller object is a subset of the data in a particular Bigger object, so I'd love to not have to duplicate data, but I would like to be able to access the data easily (and in the same manner) from both. A little code to illustrate:

```
class Smaller {
    private:
        std::vector<char> data_;
    public:
        std::vector<char> &data() { return data_ };
};

class Bigger {
    private:
        std::vector<char> data_;
        std::vector<Smaller> smallers_;
    public:
        std::vector<char> &data() { return data_ };
};
```

So something like the above is what I have right now, and the data in Smaller is read/copied independently of the data in Bigger. I started to code up a solution with Smaller having a pointer to the other data, but then that precluded having range data. I've been looking at using iterators to represent ranges within the Bigger buffer, but then I don't have the "clean" vector access via Smaller.

It would be nice if both Bigger.data() and Smaller.data() provided the same interface, while also referencing the same data buffer.

Is this something that makes sense in C++? In C, I could just have the Bigger (struct) have a char[], and have a pointer and length in both Bigger and Smaller for access. I could do something like this, but often the "C" way of doing things isn't the best way in C++.

Is the solution providing an iterator-like interface for both classes? i.e. having the vector in Bigger be completely private, and only exposing data iterators? Would this be a `std::pair<std::iterator,std::iterator>`, or wrapper of such?

Comment: Your `data()` functions returns a copy of the internal data, is this the intended behavior?

Comment: I *thought* C++ just kinda made that work efficiently, but I suppose to be correct it should be a reference? Edit incoming, and good catch.

Comment: It only depends on how you want your method to behave (and what you want to do with the returned `vector`) - With copy, it would have been easy to provide access to "sub" vector, but if you need a reference, it is much more difficult :/

Comment: @Holt, I suppose I should have mentioned that the buffer in Bigger is fairly large, hence my desire to avoid having to effectively read it in twice into each "subvector".

Comment: If you decide to use `std::vector` you need to operate using iterators to avoid copying. You could consider using `ArrayRef` of llvm, which have constructors, which create a new object referencing the old data. Another alternative is to use views on the data - then all `data()` function can return a view.

Comment: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3334.html -- And while you're waiting for that to be standardized, there are various libraries which implement something similar, such as [LLVM's ArrayRef](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1ArrayRef.html). Or you could implement it yourself, it's fairly trivial.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley shucks, it looks like 3334 would fit the bill. I'll have to look at LLVM's ArrayRef and see if it'll fit the bill here. Thanks for the suggestions.